# Proof integration identity $\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dy=\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{y}^{1}e^{x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, power-series

I have to prove this identity:
$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dy=\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{y}^{1}e^{x^2}dx$$
I've shown that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dy=\int_{0}^{1}xe^{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}(e-1)$$

After i tried to solve the second member of identity in this way:

The first part is done by substituting $x^2$ in series 
$$ e^{x}  =  1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots $$
yielding
$$e^{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} $$
Through some theorems as uniform continuity, then we can switch the order of integration and summation, that is:
$$\int_{y}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{y}^{1} x^{2n}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}*\Big(1-\frac{y^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\Big)dx$$
And from here i'm not sure how to proceed. What can i do? Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Note that $\int_{0}^{1}dx=\int_{0}^{1}dy$, so you only need to show $\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt=\int_{y}^{1}e^{t^2}dt$. Now, they are not equal as functions of $x$ and $y$

Comment: Beware in your notations. What you wrote in first line are products of 1-dim integrals but on second line you consider a 2-dim integral. Use parenthesis and let the $dx,dy$ at the end for 2-dim integrals. Thus what you are asking is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to calculate the iterated integrals is not the way here - one of those integrals will work in an elementary way, but the other won't.

No, this is a case of Fubini's theorem - the two integrals are the same because they're the same double integral over a triangle, integrated in the two possible orders. We wish to show that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1\int_y^1 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$
for nice enough $f$. The function we're trying to integrate is continuous and bounded on this bounded set, and that's certainly nice enough.

Draw the picture:

[image: Triangle]

Integrating over $y$ first, our condition is that $0\le y\le x$. Integrating over $x$ first, our condition is that $y\le x\le 1$. Then, in both cases, the outer variable runs from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: thank you for your exposure ! @jmerry